# Setting the url dynamically from static class or inheritence in ExtJS 4

Tags: url, dynamic, extjs4, store

I have the following class:

```
Ext.define('Modeller.store.Datasources', {
  extend: 'Modeller.store.Base',
  requires: ['Modeller.Defaults'],
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'api/v1.0/datasources',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that the path `api/v1.0/datasources` can be quite different. It depends how the server software has been set up. It can be `/api/...` or perhaps `/anotherapi/api` depending on if it has been installed under a virtual folder or directly under the root.

The server software api is separate from the client.

I need to set it only once and not per store load. The configuration should contain for instance `/` or `anotherapi/` and affect all proxy urls.

Is there a way to do this using ext classes?